# "Unresolved import Device" error, in uiautomator using python

Tags: android, python, eclipse, android-uiautomator

I'm writing a python code using uiautomator tool for android.
I have installed uiautomator in python using "pip install uiautomator".
I'm using eclipse IDE.

But when I try to import Device from uiautomator (like below) , I'm getting  **"Unresolved import Device"** error

```
from uiautomator import Device
```

I have also tried below possibilties.

```
from uiautomator import device
```

and

```
from uiautomator import device as d
```

But still getting "**Unresolved import device**" error

Note :
I have even downloaded uiautomator separately and added it as exterenal library in eclipse,. ( but got same error)

Please help.

Comment: can you type uiautomatorviewer in command prompt and see if it is working?

Comment: does your `pip list` command output uiautomator?

Comment: @be_good_do_good , After typing uiautomatorviewer in cmd prompt, UI Automator viewer is launched.  Yes `pip list` displayed uiautomator at output. I could see `uiautomator (0.2.6)`

Comment: Do you get import errors in command prompt as well? I mean in python shell, if type same command, do you get same errors?

Comment: @be_good_do_good, maybe you are almost there :) . In python shell , I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Good, in the eclipse project, do you see Lib/site-packages if you expand python http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2dc729y&s=9#.V617Lvl95hF